# How to display Date (angular) internet explorer browser

Tags: angular, typescript, date, internet-explorer, pipe

Angular problem:

I can't display date using internet explorer browser.

### "invalid pipe argument"

## angular #internet explorer

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and share the relevant code sections and complete error messages in your question (as text, not as images).

Comment: when i run my project in internet explorer browser it display "invalid pipe argument" and the date don't display

Comment: Can you show us how you are using your Pipe?

Comment: {{notification.created_at| date :'MM-dd-yyyy h:mm:ss a'}}

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{{notification.created_at | date:'MM/d/y h:mm:ss a'}}
```

also the medium date is pretty close to what you are looking for:

```
{{notification.created_at | date:'medium'}}
```

for further reference please check out: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: any format i used the erreur is the same ('invalid pipe argument')

Comment: if you `console.log(notification.created_at);` what does it look like?

Comment: The DatePipe is expecting a date object and not a string. Make sure your date is the correct format. 

for more information on the javascript date format look here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp